# Exclude Results from Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of creating a powershell script that extracts the permissions associated with a directory and outputs the results to a CSV. This script currently works as intended however, now I want to have it exclude the 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' and 'BUILTIN\Administrators' account from the list. Can you please tell me how I can achieve this?

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "C:\GMT\Common\" -Recurse -Force
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
    {
        $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD Group or User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
        $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
    }
}
$Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\Temp\server_permissions.csv"
```

Comment: You can filter the Object with something simple like `-notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"`. e.g. change the line to this: `$Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD Group or User'=($Access.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators";'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use an `if`-statement like so:

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "C:\GMT\Common\" -Recurse -Force
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access) {
        if (!($Access.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Administrators") -and !($Access.IdentityReference -eq "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM")) {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{
                'FolderName'       = $Folder.FullName
                'AD Group or User' = $Access.IdentityReference
                'Permissions'      = $Access.FileSystemRights
            }
            $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
    }
}
$Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\Temp\server_permissions.csv"
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. I also added "-NoTypeInformation" after "-Encoding "utf8" to remove the string above the header. Thanks again. Kieran

Answer (score 0):

If you re-factor your code a little to use the pipeline, then you can filter with `Where-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\GMT\Common\" -Recurse -Force |
    ForEach-Object {
        $folder = $_
        (Get-Acl -Path $folder.FullName).Access |
            Where-Object IdentityReference -notin "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","BUILTIN\Administrators" |
                ForEach-Object {
                    [PsCustomobject]@{
                        'FolderName'   = $folder.FullName
                        'ADGroupOrUser'= $_.IdentityReference
                        'Permissions'  = $_.FileSystemRights
                    }
                }                
     } | Export-Csv -path "C:\Temp\server_permissions.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Even if you don't want to use this method, one thing I'd recommend is to avoid using spaces in property names such as `'AD Group or User' = $Access.IdentityReference`.  While this works, it will just give you unnecessary headaches later.